# C program for bowling game

Tags: c

I need to write a program for a game of bowling. Ask the user to enter the number of games and the number of bowlers. For each bowler, get the score for each game. Display the score. Calculate the average for each bowler and display the average. Finally display the team average. 
I wrote a code, it doesn't have errors but the problem is that it doesn't count average score for players and total score for team. Need help with these calculations.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int playerTotal = 0;
    int teamTotal = 0;
    int score;
    int numgames, player, bowler, game;

    printf ("How many games?\n");
    scanf ("%d", &numgames);
    printf ("How many players?\n");
    scanf ("%d", &player);

    for (bowler = 1; bowler <= 3; bowler++)
       {
        for (game = 1; game <= 2; game++)
           {
        printf ("\nEnter the score for game %d for bowler %d: ", game, bowler);
        scanf ("%d", &score);

        playerTotal += score;
           }
        printf ("\nThe average for bowler %d is: ", bowler, playerTotal/2);

        printf ("\nThe total for the game is:", teamTotal);

        teamTotal += playerTotal;
       }


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: your for loops are using hard coded limits rather than `numgames` and `player`.  why?

Comment: Your prints also have very strange setups.  You need one variable reference for each variable you try to print.  Your second print has one %d, and two variables, your third has none, and one variable.  You also only have one PlayerTotal variable, how are you holding data for multiple players?

Answer (score 3):

It's nothing to do with "not counting" - you're just not printing them. This:

```
printf ("\nThe average for bowler %d is: ", bowler, playerTotal/2);
printf ("\nThe total for the game is:", teamTotal);
```

should be:

```
printf ("\nThe average for bowler %d is: %.1f", bowler, playerTotal / 2.0);
printf ("\nThe running team total is: %d", teamTotal);
```

Note the change from `2` to `2.0`, since `playerTotal` is an `int`, but if the total is odd then the average will (or should) have a `.5` on the end.

You're also going to want to set `playerTotal = 0;` at the start of your outer `for` loop, otherwise each player is going to get the scores of all the bowlers who entered their scores previously, which is probably not all that fair of a scoring system. You should change:

```
for (bowler = 1; bowler <= 3; bowler++)
       {
        for (game = 1; game <= 2; game++)
           {
```

to:

```
for (bowler = 1; bowler <= player; ++bowler) {
    playerTotal = 0;

    for (game = 1; game <= numgames; ++game) {
```

which will also loop for the same number of times that you had the user enter. If you do this, you'll also need to change:

```
printf ("\nThe average for bowler %d is: %.1f", bowler, playerTotal / 2.0);
```

to:

```
printf ("\nThe average for bowler %d is: %.1f", bowler,
            playerTotal / (double) numgames);
```

to divide your average by the correct number of games.

Other than those things, you made a pretty nice attempt.